# @font-Face not working on web server

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

My website's fonts are not working...

I am working on a website and my css has a property in it called @font-face
when I already uploaded the site on a web server... In my browser(chrome) it is working great but when I asked someone to check it for me the site is pretty messed up. When I checked it also in mozilla it is also messed up...
I use custom fonts...

FONTS:

air millhouse italic

Guardians

A song for jennifer

Fredericka the great

if you need the code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Air Millhouse  Italic";
  src: url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825593225.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825593225.woff") format("woff"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825593225.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825593225.svg") format("svg");
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron);

@font-face {
  font-family: "Fredericka the Great";
  src: local("☺"),
       url("FrederickatheGreat-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "a song for jennifer";
  src: local("☺"),
       url("asongforjennifer.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Guardians";
  src: local("☺"),
       url("Guardians.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "quicksand";
  src: local("☺"),
       url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand") format("opentype");
}


h1{
 text-align: center;
 color:#009900;
 font-family: air millhouse italic;
 font-size: 70px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 color: #6500ff;
 font-family: guardians;
 opacity:0.7; 
 font-size: 33px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 50px;
}

h2:hover{
 color:green;
 font-size: 40px;
}

#dew1{
 opacity: 0.5px;
 max-height: 60px;
 max-width: 60px; 
 position: relative;
 bottom:228px;
 right:130px;
}

#catdew{
 max-height: 200px;
 max-width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 bottom:315px;
}

#catdew:hover{
 max-height: 250px;
 max-width: 250px;
}

#dance1{
 max-height: 135px;
 max-width: 135px;
 position: relative;
 bottom:510px;
 left:400px;
 z-index: -1;
}

#dance2{
 max-height: 135px;
 max-width: 135px;
 position: relative;
 bottom:510px;
 right:400px;
 z-index: -1;
}

h3{
 font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;;
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
 position: relative;
 bottom:470px;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#dew{
 color:white;
 font-family: courier new;
 text-align: center;
}

#dew:hover{
 color:yellow;
 font-family: arial black;
}

#down{
 color: #009900;
 font-family: fredericka the Great;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 500px;
}

#patient{
 color: white;
 font-family: courier new;
 text-align: center;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 500px;
}

#then{
 text-align: center;
 color: #009900;
 font-family: fredericka the Great;

}

#ab{
 color: #009900;
 font-family: fredericka the Great;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 645px;
}

#not{
 font-family: a song for jennifer;
 color: #009900;
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 500px;
}

#adr{
 font-family: a song for jennifer;
 color: #009900;
 font-size: 23px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 550px;
 left: 250px;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are the fonts you're using installed on your computer or your server?

Comment: Do you see any error on firefox console?

Comment: technical note: browsers have moved on since that syntax. SVG fonts are no longer a thing ([no real browsersupports them anymore](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts)). In fact, if you have the `woff` version, that's pretty much enough on its own to support [any browser that matters](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff).

Comment: service http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, which converts font to the desired format

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the path for the fonts:

```
url("FrederickatheGreat-Regular.ttf")
url("asongforjennifer.ttf")
url("Guardians.ttf")
```

These fonts are probably installed on your computer, but not on your friends computer. Look how all the other fonts on your code have complete paths, you need to either upload the fonts to a server(if you have the rights to do so) or find a provider online, like [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) that you used for "quicksand" font.